# Swapping values of undefined size with memcpy

Tags: c, swap, memcpy, void-pointers, incomplete-type

I am trying to swap the value of two elements in an array, where i know their size as a variable, my code looks like that:

```
void function(void *array, size_t size) {
    /*in this example the array's members are 2
    and i want to swap them*/
    void *help = malloc(size);

    memcpy(help, &array[0], size);
    memcpy(&array[0], &array[1], size);
    memcpy(&array[1], help, size);
    free(help);
}
```

Am i missing something?

Comment: You need `free(help);` at the end. Otherwise it's fine.

Comment: `&array[0]` and `array[1]` is wrong, you can not use array notation nor pointer arithmetic with `void *`, instead, consider using `char *` or `unsigned char *`

Comment: @DavidRanieri Well, given an `void *` array, how could i switch it to `char *` ?

Comment: Just `(char*)array`. But `array` is an array of elements of `size` size? So don't you need to copy from `(char*)array + size` position?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type `void` is incomplete type. So you may not dereference a pointer of the type `void *`.

Write the function like

```
void function(void *array, size_t size) {
    /*in this example the array's members are 2
    and i want to swap them*/
    void *help = malloc(size);

    memcpy(help, array, size);
    memcpy( array, ( char * )array + size, size);
    memcpy( ( char * )array + size, help, size);
    free(help);
}
```

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void function(void *array, size_t size) {
    /*in this example the array's members are 2
    and i want to swap them*/
    void *help = malloc(size);

    memcpy(help, array, size);
    memcpy( array, ( char * )array + size, size);
    memcpy( ( char * )array + size, help, size);
    free(help);
}

int main(void) 
{
    int a[] = { 1, 2 };
    const size_t N = sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ ) printf( "%d ", a[i] );
    putchar( '\n' );

    function( a, sizeof( int ) );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ ) printf( "%d ", a[i] );
    putchar( '\n' );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
1 2 
2 1
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! Of course the function i am writing is not that simple, as i have a large array and i search for the elements that i will switch, but based on your answer i understood how to do it.

Comment: Another approach would be to use an automatic array of size e.g. 256, write a function that can swap blocks of up to 256 bytes, and then write a function to swap blocks of arbitrary size by using the first function on 256-byte-or-smaller chunks.